# DD-WRT virtual interface or separate router for guest network

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

Just installed [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) open source firmware on my Netgear [WNDR3700](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wndr3700.aspx) WiFi router and was wondering whether using a virtual interface to make a guest network or connecting my Linksys [WRT54GS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54GS) WiFi router up to one of the Ethernet ports and run a guest network off that, I'm mainly worried about the performance hit the virtual interface could possibly cause for the primary network. And security I need the 2 networks to be completely separate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless you are planning to have just one wired guest at a time, you will need a router anyway. In either case, [this Web page](http://www.geek-pages.com/articles-for-geeks-mainmenu-2/1-latest/27-dd-wrt-setting-up-a-separate--isolated-vlan-on-port-4-with-dhcp?showall=1) provides a simple, yet fully functional, detailed how-to to set up a VLAN on your DD-WRT router. This will work whether you wish to attach a router to the port scheduled for the `other` VLAN, or just a PC.

As for performance,DD-WRT lets you configure QoS in the menu NAT/QoS-> QoS. There's a subsection to be configured called `Netmask Proprity`, which the on-line help describes thus:

> Netmask Priority: You may specify priority for all traffic from a given IP address or IP Range.

Configure as needed.

Edit:

This is provided in order to include Journeyman Geek's comment. There are at least three ways to do this, which I mention in order of decreasing cost.

The suggestion to use your old router is still valid. If all you wish is to add a guest wifi network, this is automatically obtained by using your old router.

You might think this is a bit of an overkill, for just a guest wifi network, and you would be right. If this is indeed all you are interested in, simply replace the router with an AP (Access Point), plugged into the VLAN port of your DD-WRT router, and you are done; it is understood that the VLAN configuration needs to be done again following the guide I already referenced.

Lastly, some routers support dual SSIDs. The wrt54gs is certainly one of them. You can find a detailed guide to do that [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/153827/), it basically comes down to instructing your DD-WRT router to have two completely separate wifi networks at the same time, with different IPs and a configuration that prevents one network from talking to the other one.

Comment: I think he means having a second, isolated wireless SSID on Netgear, not a wired guest network

Comment: Ya I wasn't talking wired at all, just looking for a wireless guest network

Comment: @Ryan Please read my Edit

Comment: My router does support dual ssids I was just concerned about a speed decrease if I chose to go that route. If I used my old router what settings what have to made to ensure that the networks were completely separate

Comment: Those in the Web page referenced above are sufficient.